# Pictionary rules clarification

Tags: pictionary

We played Pictionary the other day, and there were a couple of points of play that were unclear from the rules, and which I also can't find answers to online (though can find other people asking the same questions), so I was hoping someone could clarify.

Firstly, after you correctly guess a clue, you roll the dice, move, and draw another card. Do you re-set the time at this point, or do you continue your go in the unused time?

Secondly, in an "all-play" situation, if another team guesses the answer, they then take control of the dice. Once they then fail to guess an answer correctly, does play continue to the team to their left, or to the left of the team whose go it originally was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/pictionary.pdf) on Hasbro's website, there is an explicit rule stating that players get 60 seconds per word (bottom of the first page):

> The timer is turned for another 60 seconds for each new word.

The rules also specify what happens when a team fails to guess their word (emphasis mine):

> If a word is not identified within the time limit, **play continues to the left**.

There aren't any special rules addressing the order of play after an *All Play*, so this rule would dictate that the next team to play would be the one to the left of the team that won the *All Play* round. Since Pictionary is a party game, there's nothing stopping your play group from using a house rule like this:

> After the team that won the *All Play* fails, play would continue with the team to the left of the team that drew the *All Play*.

Comment: Those rules make it much clearer than the ones included with our edition of the game, which only mention turning the timer at the start of a turn.

Comment: For reference, our edition was published by Mattel, and the version of the rules included is very similar to that on their website: http://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/BJM16-ENG.pdf